# Why does background-gradient not scale?

Tags: html, css, gradient

My CSS gradient in the background does not scale, what can I do?
I plan to do a HTML layout in percentage, but the body gradient is too short.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/snGVt/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box round"><img src="http://goo.gl/wv4zi" /></div>
    <div class="box round"><img src="http://goo.gl/wv4zi" /></div>
</div>
```

```
html{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

body {
    width:100%;
    background: #0e89b6; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0e89b6 0%, #00142c 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#0e89b6), color-stop(100%,#00142c)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #0e89b6 0%,#00142c 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #0e89b6 0%,#00142c 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #0e89b6 0%,#00142c 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #0e89b6 0%,#00142c 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0e89b6', endColorstr='#00142c',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.wrapper {

    width: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.box{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.box > img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: scales perfectly for me. Can you post screen shot of what it looks like for you? What browser are you using?

Comment: Show us your gradient style

Comment: remove the width/height declaration from `html`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the html width and height styles to "min-height: 100%" and min-width: 100%"

```
html{
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size`.

CSS3 gradients can be considered as functions that generate a fixed-sized image, so they still need to be controlled with the size property.

Answer (score 0):

In IE9 there was some margin around the edge of the gradient. You should set your `body` and `html` to have no margin. Is that what you were having a problem with?

```
html,body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Note this wasn't an issue for me in other browsers.